# Initializing a 2 dimensions array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I want to initializing a 2 dimensions Array in PHP and I don't know How to declare a 2d array of size (1,N) in php with all values as Zeros?

```
$Orders_C  = array(1,N);
```

I am not sure if this is correct syntax or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**PHP** doesnot have 2d array ,but instead it has array of array. You can use the code below to initialize as you said.

```
$Orders_C=array_fill(0,1, array_fill(0, N,0));
```

Here the `array_fill` first return an array filled with **0** from index **0** to **N**.And again the same array is filled to the new array upto index 1.Hence you will get an array within array.

Answer (score 0):

Generic solution for any count of columns and rows could be:

```
$maxRows = 5;
$maxCols = 5;
$orders = [];
for ($col = 0; $col < $maxCols; $col++) {
    for ($row = 0; $row < $maxRows; $row++) {
        $orders[$col] = $row;
    }
}
```

And because you want 2d array like (1, N) then you can simplify it

```
$orders = [];
for ($i = 0; $i < $maxRows; $i++) {
    $orders[0][] = 0;
}
```